# symfony2 bundle autoloading failed

Tags: symfony, bundle

I happen to get all the symfony problems of the creation...

I want to create a new project.

I copy the '*symfony2*' folder, rename it then:

```
 php app/console generate:bundle
```

It says:

```
  Generating the bundle code: OK
  Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED
  Confirm automatic update of your Kernel [yes]? 
  Enabling the bundle inside the Kernel: OK
  Confirm automatic update of the Routing [yes]? 
  Importing the bundle routing resource: FAILED

  The command was not able to configure everything automatically.  
  You must do the following changes manually.                      

  - Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
  namespace in the "autoload" section:

  Bundle MddevPsavBundle is already imported.
```

Why is this? When I did not have that problem last time I have done the same command?

How can I solve this exactly? and what shall I add exactly into that `composer.json` file ??

I have tried something but I get:

```
  Fatal error: Class 'Mddev\PsavBundle\MddevPsavBundle' not found in
  /var/www/projetQ/app/AppKernel.php on line 22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your bundle namespace doesn't follow conventions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name

You should rather use `Mddev\Bundle\MddevPsavBundle` or `Mddev\MddevPsavBundle` as a bundle namespace.

Comment: same autoloading problem happened though...even with a conventional namespace

Comment: what is the syntax then and where to place ? "Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
  namespace in the "autoload" section"

Comment: Everything in src directory should be autoloaded automatically for you so you don't have to do anything as long as your namespaces follow PSR-0 standard.

Comment: Again... make sure your class name REALLY follows PSR-0. Another thing to remember is to rebuild the autoloader when you define a new namespace (see composer docs).

Comment: I used the example namespace in the Symfony docs (Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle) and I got this error.

Comment: See my answer if you are still stuck

Comment: @AndrewAtkinson check out my answer, no need to edit the composer.json

Answer (score 10):

If you are getting the problem:

```
The command was not able to configure everything automatically.  
You must do the following changes manually.
```

Which then tells you to:

```
- Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
namespace in the "autoload" section:
```

Assuming you have followed the [bundle name conventions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name) correctly, then you will need to:

---

**Add your new bundle to the composer.json file**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "currentbundle\\": "src/",
        "YOURNEWBUNDLE\\": "src/",            
    }
}
```

**You then need to run install on composer again**

```
composer -n install --dev
```

You should then have both of the bundles autoloaded

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to do this. src folder is a fallback dir by default (every namespace which was not previously configured is loaded from there).

Comment: This is what I had to do to get the bundle to load. The reason behind it, I am not sure.

Comment: @JakubZalas its a namespace issue, just edit the namespaces in the appkernel and the bundle's class(my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

I just had this exact problem.  app/console generate:bundle was failing the autoload check and the src directory was not being created.  I am so used to taking the default answers that I didn't notice that the src directory was pointing to the cache directory.

I typed in the proper path and all was well.

I guess familiarity really does breed contempt.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Error because I didn't have composer installed before running generate:bundle.

Once I installed composer, tried the command again (after deleting the files that bundle created and the code from app/AppKernal.php) it worked right away

Answer (score 0):

when generating bundles form the command line the generator does not take into account the directory that the bundle is in, this might cause problems while adding vendor prefixes to your bundle, you need to make sure of two things for this to work

1. check namespace in `AppKernel.php` > `registerBundles()`
2. check namespace in the bundle's class
3. run `composer update` just to make sure autoloader is created correctly

eg:-  `namespace Acme\UserBundle;` in UserBundle.php

```
|-----|
|    src
|       |
|      Acme
|          |
|        UserBundle
|               .
|               .
|           UserBundle.php
```

And Inside `AppKernel.php` have `new Acme\UserBundle\UserBundle(),`

Answer (score 0):

For fix this error is necesary add in `composer.json` this code:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
```

Always that all Bundles are in `/src`
This change was my solution in `Symfony 3.3.x`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Change composer.json  in autoload

```
"autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Composer\\CaBundle\\": "src"
            }
        },
```

add run the command `composer dumpautoload`